# How can I get the buttons to appear in the same general locations across different devices? Xamarin.Android

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I made alternate layouts for each screen size and orientation. I tweaked the padding parameters in each layout so the buttons will appear where I want them and they look good in Xamarin Studio, [image: Xamarin Studio] but they appear in the wrong places in both the Xamarin Android Player [image: Xamarin Android Player] and on my device.

I tried to tackle this problem in a previous post but I got sidetracked. The one thing I took away though is that I probably should be using another parameter in the properties pane besides padding. Perhaps gravity or something like that?  How can I get the buttons to appear in the same general locations across different devices?

Comment: You should either have your `android:layout_width` set to `fill_parent` or You're probably better off using `LinearLayout` with respective `android:layout_weight` set.

Answer (score 0):

Give a try to the new ConstraintLayout. You will need Android Studio 2.2 for it

Here is a some documentation:
https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout/index.html

Comment: I'm using Xamarin Studio and it's not available in the toolbox.

Comment: In this case I suggest using android:layout_weight. Look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3995825/what-does-androidlayout-weight-mean

Comment: You could always alter the layout using `Android Studio` as it fully supports `ConstraintLayout` and then move the final layout to `Xamarin Studio`.